# List<int> as entity model class data member + won't display

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

I have an entity class model for an Azure database. I want one of the data members to be a List, or something similar. Essentially I'm hoping to be able to store a variable number of 'int's in the entity. So far it compiles but it doesn't display the list info. Is this possible? Is there a better way to store a variable size container within an entity class model?

My entity class

```
public class Attribute
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AttributeID { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string AttributeName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(10000), Display(Name = "Attribute Description"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "F_in")]
    public int F_in { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "F_out")]
    public int F_out { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "F_sum")]
    public int F_sum { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public List<int> R1 { get; set; }

}
```

My markup

```
<asp:FormView ID="AttributeDetail" runat="server" ItemType="Trojan.Models.Attribute" SelectMethod ="GetAttribute" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <h1><%#:Item.AttributeName %></h1>
        </div>
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="/Catalog/Images/<%#:Item.ImagePath %>" style="border:solid; height:300px" alt="<%#:Item.AttributeName %>"/>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>  
                <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align:left;">
                    <b>Description:</b><br /><%#:Item.Description %>
                    <br />
                    <span><b>F_in:</b>&nbsp;<%#: String.Format("{0:d}", Item.F_in) %></span>
                    <span><b>F_out:</b>&nbsp;<%#: String.Format("{0:d}", Item.F_out) %></span>
                    <br />
                    <span><b>Attribute Number:</b>&nbsp;<%#:Item.AttributeID %></span>
                    <br />
                    <span><b>R1 Relations: </b>&nbsp;<%#:Item.R1 %></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

My code behind

```
public partial class AttributeDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public IQueryable<Trojan.Models.Attribute> GetAttribute(
                        [QueryString("AttributeID")] int? AttributeId,
                        [RouteData] string AttributeName)
    {
        var _db = new Trojan.Models.AttributeContext();
        IQueryable<Trojan.Models.Attribute> query = _db.Attributes;
        if (AttributeId.HasValue && AttributeId > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.AttributeID == AttributeId);
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AttributeName))
        {
            query = query.Where(p =>
                      String.Compare(p.AttributeName, AttributeName) == 0);
        }
        else
        {
            query = null;
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

I forgot to add the databaseinitializer where I set the list

```
private static List<Attribute> GetAttributes()
    {
        var Attributes = new List<Attribute> {
            new Attribute
            {
                AttributeID = 1,
                AttributeName = "Specification",
                Description = "Insertion",
                ImagePath="one.png",
                F_in = 0,
                F_out = 3,
                CategoryID = 1,
                CategoryName = "Chip Life Cycle",
                R1 = new List<int> {2},
    }
```

Comment: It's not really good practice to use lists of things in a database - it violates the first normal form (each attribute/intersection of row with column should have only scalar values). Also I am not seeing where you are defining what's in the list.

Comment: What is this "won't display" means? Nothing or something like error? And why is your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answer you expected, but maybe it can be a workaround.
Change this:

```
<span><b>R1 Relations: </b>&nbsp;<%#:Item.R1 %></span>
```

to this:

```
<span><b>R1 Relations: </b>&nbsp;<%#GetList(:Item.R1) %></span>
```

And in your code behind, add this:

```
string delimeter = ",";
var item = items.Select(a => a.ToString()).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(item.Aggregate((i, j) => i.ToString() + delimeter + j.ToString()));
```

I don't really know about Trojan.Models.Attribute (and syntax within it). But, as you can see, the logic is just simple. You just convert it to string before display it to listView member